# How do i find the dots closest to the middle with my code (based on number of dots asked)

Tags: java

So I have the following code and I need to find the number of dots closest to the middle of the row that are not '#'. Since in this case I'm looking for 3 dots I need to find the 3 dots closest to the middle and get the starting index of those 3 dots. I need the 3 dots to be next to each other. It can't be hard coded in case I need to change the string and in case I need to change the number of dots I'm looking for.

```
        int numOfDots = 3;
        String line = "...#.#...#";
        for (int i =0; i < line.length(); i++) {

        }
```

i.e.

```
##..##...#  //Index of 6 for 3 consecutive dots closest to middle
....#..### //Index of 1 
#..#..##.. //None
..##.....# //Index of 4(the middle column)
...#.#...# //Index of 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
 int numOfDots = 3;
    String line = "...#.#...#";
    String[] arry = line.split("#");

    int middle = arry.length%2==0?arry.length/2:(arry.length/2 +1);

    for (int i=middle,j = middle; i >= 0; i--,j++) {
        if(arry[i].length()==numOfDots) {
            System.out.println("Result Index in arry :" + i);
            break;
        }
        if(j<arry.length&&arry[j].length()==numOfDots) {
            System.out.println("Result Index in arry :" + j);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It needs to be the dots closest to the middle, in this case it would be dot 6 and the dots following it. The beginning dots are farther from it and they also start at the index 0 not 2

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I added it to the main body

Comment: I can't understand your example. 
can you write step by step ?